# Getting started in Kivy, need assistance with .kv files

Tags: button, label, kivy, boxlayout

I'm trying to make a simple app to monitor some IO And have a push button screen. I'm getting started on the framework of how the screen would work using kivy as my gui development. I'm wanting to do a lot of label updating based on variables, so the desire to do that has led me into using a .kv file and kivy properties. Admittedly, I know very little about these things it's just what I know from googling and trying to figure out what I need to do.

Regardless, I'm trying to do some basic framework to get started with a .kv file and though my main.py compiles, it does not display any buttons. I'm familiar with adding buttons to a layout done through the python language but I'm looking to do it more in the kivy style. Please help!

Here is my main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import random

class YourWidget(Widget):
    random_number = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(YourWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.random_number = str(random.randint(1, 100))

        def change_text(self):
            self.random_number = str(random.randint(1, 100))

class YourApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return YourWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    YourApp().run()
```

and here is my *your.kv*

```
#:kivy 1.9.2

<YourWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10

        Button:
            id: btn1
            text: "Change Text"
            on_release: root.change_text()
            size_hint: .3, .3

        Button:
            id: btn2
            text: "Exit App"
            on_release: App.get_running_app().stop()
            size_hint: .3, .3

        Label:
            id: lbl1
            Font_size: 70
            text:root.random_number
            size_hint: .3, .3
```

Let me know anything you could assist with. I'm very new to python and extremely new to packages like kivy. Thank you! Another note is currently I am developing this on a monitor and will port to a touch screen later.

Comment: Delete canvas from kv file.

Comment: You don't add widgets to `canvas`, you add them to `Widget`. Canvas is for something [else](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/graphics.html). Basically: `<YW>:  BoxLayout:`

Comment: Tried deleting canvas and no improvement. App runs and the screen stays black, no buttons or labels are shown.

I've tried naming it *Your.kv*, Your.kv, YourWidget.kv, main.kv, none of these seem to impact it. What is the proper syntax for naming a kv file?

Current code for the KV file is reflected in original post now.

Comment: It should be named `your.kv`, note that it's lowercase (which is what Kivy is truly looking for, though Your.kv will also work on a case insensitive filesystem).

Comment: That was my issue all along! But now I know the proper syntax. I looked around the kivy instructions for it a bit didn't find anything explaining the rules very well. Thank you!

Comment: Here is the explanation: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html

Answer (score 0):

Rename your.kv to yourwidget.kv

Answer (score -1):

when drawing graphics on the canvas the class or Widget name of your game must be reflected also in the kivy file. s